# rename a windows service name without reinstalling it again

Tags: windows-services, rename

Is there  a way to rename a windows service name without reinstalling it again? After the rename the SC or NET START/STOP commands to restart service should only be able to stop / start service using the newly renamed name.

Comment: You can change the display name but not the service name.  (But uninstalling and reinstalling a service is a fast, lightweight operation.  No real reason not to do it that way.)